# linq query to return a string from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a products table and an activities table.Each product is made up of different activities.What i want is to display a product name,price,etc and the all the activities (i.e all the activities in one column) which are part of that product in a datagrid using linq 
 Below is my query

```
using (bungeedbEntities context = new bungeedbEntities())
{
   var bookingData = from con in context.bookings
   join agn in context.agents on con.main_agent_id equals agn.code

    select new POS_LINK.BusinessObjects.Bookings 
     {
       Product = con.product_name,
       Activity = String.Join(",", (from con1 in context.bookings
                                  join acp in context.booking_activity on con1.code equals acp.booking_code
                                  join agn in context.agents on con1.main_agent_id equals agn.code
                                  join act in context.activities on acp.activity_code equals act.code
                                  select act.name).ToArray()),
    ReservationCode = con.main_agent_voucher,
    CostOfSale = 0.00M,
    DateOfActivity = (DateTime)con.date_of_activity,
    Notes = con.notes,
    Quantity = (int)con.pax,
                          Child_quantity = 0,
                          Child_cost_percentage = 0,
                          CostPerPerson = 0.00M,
                          SubAgentRef = "56789",
                          SubAgentName = con.sub_agent_name,
                          ClientName = con.client_name,
                          MainAgent = agn.agent_name,
                          Consultant2 = con.sub_agent_consultant                                      
                      };
    return bookingData.ToList();
```

On running i get the following error- LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I seem to have run out of ideas anyone with a better solution to this would save me from a lot of head scratching

Comment: `String.Join` does not translate within Linq to SQL, also if it would, you would be executing a sub select for each result row which is not performant at all. Consider grouping results and doing the join in a later step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps: first step selects the data, while the second step translates it to a string with `string.Join`:

```
var bookingData = (from con in context.bookings
    join agn in context.agents on con.main_agent_id equals agn.code
    select new { // Construct an anonymous type with the relevant parts
        Product = con.product_name,
        ActivityData = (from con1 in context.bookings
                      join acp in context.booking_activity on con1.code equals acp.booking_code
                      join agn in context.agents on con1.main_agent_id equals agn.code
                      join act in context.activities on acp.activity_code equals act.code
                      select act.name),
        ReservationCode = con.main_agent_voucher,
        DateOfActivity = (DateTime)con.date_of_activity,
        Notes = con.notes,
        Quantity = (int)con.pax,
        SubAgentName = con.sub_agent_name,
        ClientName = con.client_name,
        MainAgent = agn.agent_name,
        Consultant2 = con.sub_agent_consultant                                      
    }).AsEnumerable() // Bring this into memory
    .Select(p => new POS_LINK.BusinessObjects.Bookings {
        Product = p.Product,
        Activity = string.Join(", ", p.ActivityData.ToArray()),
        ReservationCode = p.ReservationCode,
        CostOfSale = 0.00M,
        Notes = p.Notes,
        Quantity = p.Quantity,
        Child_quantity = 0,
        Child_cost_percentage = 0,
        CostPerPerson = 0.00M,
        SubAgentRef = "56789",
        SubAgentName = p.SubAgentName,
        ClientName = p.ClientName,
        MainAgent = p.MainAgent,
        Consultant2 = p.Consultant2  
    });
return bookingData.ToList();
```

The idea here is simple: first, you construct an anonymous type that has all relevant information, including an enumeration of `acc.name`s, then you force it into memory by calling `AsEnumerable()`, and finally construct your `POS_LINK.BusinessObjects.Bookings` objects using LINQ-to-Object, which understands `string.Join`.